# Problem in using facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am making my own application, which fetches data from facebook using facebook graph api. The trouble i am getting is that whenever i start my application and click on login button it redirects to com.facebook.katana and invalid_key error generates. On the other hand when i uninstall the com.facebook.katana application from my phone, my application starts working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Android FB SDK

### Set up single sign-on

Optionally, you can make your login system more seamless by incorporating single sign-on.

- **Register your application's Android key hash.** This is used by Facebook to ensure that another app can't impersonate your app when talking to the Facebook Android app.

  1. Generate the key hash:

     ```
     keytool -exportcert -alias [alias] -keystore [keystore]
     | openssl sha1 -binary
     | openssl base64
     ```
  2. In the Facebook developer settings, go to the **Mobile and Devices** tab.
  3. In the **Android** section, enter the key hash in the **Key Hash** field.
- Insert a call to the authorizeCallback() method at the top of your Activity's onActivityResult() function. (If onActivityResult doesn't already exist, then create it)

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 // ... anything else your app does onActivityResult
}